# How to release iOS app to App Store for client

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am trying to figure out how to release an app for a customer. I need to do the entire release process for the customer.

I have been added as Team Admin in Dev Center and can choose the customers account when logging in to Dev Center.

It seems i need the private key in order to sign the app for the customer. I can download the Distribution Certificate of the customer, but when trying to build the archive with the Provisioning Profile in XCode i get the text: "Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in your keychains", so i cannot archive and sign the binary.

Do i need to get the private key from the customer in order to be able to release in his company name or am i doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need a private key. The entire process is detailed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ApplicationDevelopmentOverview/DeliverYourAppontheAppStore/DeliverYourAppontheAppStore.html). You'll need to build and sign the app using the private key, then submit to to apple for review.

Comment: Just to clarify, the customer is worried about handing out their private key, my understanding is that when they give me their private key as well "invite" me in Dev Center as well as iTunes Connect i can do it all for them. As soon as i am done releasing they can revoke my access to both Dev Center and iTunes Connect, meaning the private key is useless to me?

Comment: Yes, also they should regenerate a new private key afterwards.